# Running a Job from Autosys every X minutes

Tags: autosys

I am looking to run a console application triggered from Autosys every X minutes.

The following commands do not seem to provide this capability
start_times: Exact time each day a job will run [cannot be
used with start_mins]
start_mins: Minutes after each hour a job will execute
[cannot be used with start_times]

The solution that I can see at the moment is to set start_mins : 0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55

This is ok if the time interval is 5 minutes, but becomes a little cumbersome if the interval is 1 or 2 minutes.

Is there any way to configure Autosys to easily repeat a job every x minutes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is only one way for autosys to start a job every minute -
start_mins: 0,1,2..59